# Не переключается симулятор IOS

Tags: xcode, objective-c, iphone

Добрый день, вот такая беда - установил Xcode 5.1 появились проблемы.
Запускаю приложение, оно показывается как для IPhone Retina (4 inch 64-bit), при запущенном пытаюсь поменять на другое:
Аппаратура->Устройство->IPhone Retina (3.5 inch) или любое другое, приложение вылетает, переходит к main.m и зеленым подсвечивает сроку:
return UIApplicationMain(argc, argv, nil, NSStringFromClass([AppDelegate class])); Thread 1: signal SIGTERM
и все больше никаких сообщений, ни лога, ничего.

Подскажите где копать?
Спасибо

Comment: А так воообще это была бы киллер фича xCode смотреть окно приложения в разных симуляторах без перезапуска приложеия. Но для Apple это фантастика )

Answer (score 0, accepted):

В Xcode 5.1 много багов, к примеру, на старых проектах сториборды растягиваются, переходы Segue некорое перестают работать после компиляции, некоторые библиотеки он не видит. Ставил его себе, откатился назад, на версию 5.0.2. Ах да, ещё проблема с системой контроля версиями у меня была, с Xсodе не мог откатиться назад.

Советую [загрузить](https://developer.apple.com/downloads/index.action?name=Xcode) старую версию.

Comment: Да, да и сегвеи как сейча выяснилось не работают. Буду откатываться.

Comment: Лечил проблему таким же путём, в интернете уже масса комментариев по проблемам в Xcode 5.1.

Comment: Странно: ни одной подобной проблемы не встретил, напротив, все стало работать лучше. Разве что несколько новых ворнингов словил.

Answer (score 0):

Просто при смене схемы xCode закрывает сессию дебагера, который вылетает с ошибкой выхода. Это нормально. Просто либо завершайте работу приложения и потом меняйте схему, либо просто заного запускайте дебагер.

Comment: Дак в том то и проблема, когда меняю схему - приложение вылетает, в симуляторе становится та схема которую я выбрал при вылете (например 3.5). Затем снова запускаю дебагер, он опять запускается в IPhone Retina (4 inch 64-bit) :(

Comment: а перезапуск икскода не помогает?

Comment: нет, много чего пробовал, ничего не помогло